# jOOq MERGE In Oracle

Tags: java, sql, jooq

It feels like I'm close, but I cannot figure out how to do something like the below in jOOq.

```sql
MERGE INTO USER_ASSIGNMENTS ua
USING (
          SELECT core_object_id
          FROM core_objects
          WHERE exists(SELECT *
                       FROM LKU_CODE lc JOIN LKU_CODE_TYPE lct
                               ON lc.LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID = lct.LKU_CODE_TYPE_ID AND lct.CODE_TYPE = 'OBJECT_TYPE' AND
                                  lc.CODE = 'PORTFOLIOS'
                       WHERE lc.LKU_CODE_ID = core_objects.OBJECT_TYPE_ID) AND object_id = 83
      ) "co"
ON (ua.CORE_OBJECT_ID = "co".CORE_OBJECT_ID AND USER_ID = 24 AND SECTION = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET create_date = sysdate, created_by = '24', capabilities = 12
    WHERE capabilities <> 12
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
    (CAPABILITIES, CORE_OBJECT_ID, CREATE_DATE, CREATED_BY, SECTION, USER_ID)
VALUES (5, "co".CORE_OBJECT_ID, sysdate, '24', 1, 24);
```

The big thing to note is that I'm trying to use the value returned by USING, so I have to alias it *and* `.values()` has to accept a field call.  I think I can get around the `.values()` issue using the `.values(Collection<?>)` call, bundling things, including that field, into a Collection, so I think that I have that part.  What concerns me is that I cannot do an `.as()` call after `.using()`.  If I make the `USING` query a "table" via `.asTable()`, supplying an alias, will that let me call the field?  Here's kind of what I have at the moment:

```java
Table<Record1<BigDecimal>> usingStatement = readContext
        .select(_co.CORE_OBJECT_ID)
        .from(_co)
        .where(DSL.exists(readContext.select(_lc.fields()).from(
                _lc.join(_lct).onKey(Keys.LC_LCT___FK)
                        .and(_lc.CODE.equal(capability.getObjectTypeCode()))
                        .and(_lct.CODE_TYPE.equal(LkuCodeTypeLookup.OBJECT_TYPE))))).asTable("sdf");
...

return writeContext
                    .mergeInto(_ua)
                    .using(usingStatement)
                    .on(sectionalConditions.and(_ua.CORE_OBJECT_ID.equal(coidField)))
                    .whenMatchedThenUpdate()
                    .set(_ua.CREATE_DATE, time)
                    .set(_ua.CREATED_BY, creator)
                    .set(_ua.CAPABILITIES, capabilities)
                    .where(_ua.CAPABILITIES.notEqual(capabilities))
                    .whenNotMatchedThenInsert(_ua.CAPABILITIES, _ua.CORE_OBJECT_ID, _ua.CREATE_DATE,
                            _ua.CREATED_BY, _ua.SECTION, _ua.USER_ID)
                    .values(capabilities, gcoid, time, creator, section, uuid).execute();
```

A "straight merge" using dual is simple in jOOq, but I'd like to try to combine that select into the merge to save queries and let the DB do what it does best, so I'm trying not to have to get core_object_id in another query, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aliasing really happens on the table (i.e. the select), not on some artefact returned by the `USING` clause. At least, that's how jOOQ models it. You have already correctly aliased your `usingStatement` variable. Now all you have to do is dereference the desired column from it, e.g.:

```
usingStatement.field(_co.CORE_OBJECT_ID);
```

This will look for the column named `CORE_OBJECT_ID` in the `usingStatement` table.

Comment: Freaking awesome!  Thank you!

Comment: (and that dereferencing piece is a new nugget that I didn't know I could do -- I can use that instead of that crazy double Field thing in my other post; thank you so much for the help and the tool!)